# Chord change question (C#m, F# and G#)

Tags: chords

So this song is a no capo song. It’s an all barre chord song, it’s simple but a pain. The song is 8 minutes long of all barre chords. It’s a C#m, F#m, A (barred version), and G# in that order. My hand cramps and hurts too much from doing all barre. How can I play the chords easier by putting a capo somewhere? Like A (which is easy) chord, if I put a capo on second fret and play G, it makes the A chord. So is there an easier way at playing these chords if I had a capo on somewhere to where it changed the shape?

Comment: Could you post the sheet music? It would make it easier to see what the problem is.

Comment: With an A and a G#, there's nowhere you can put a capo and play all 'open' chords.

Comment: The song is GUNSLINGERS GLORY BY the dead south

Answer (score 2):

You could put the capo on the 4th fret and play open chords Am, Dm, F (the F would have to be barred), E. 1 out of 4 barred chords isn’t bad. Like @Tim says they can’t all be open chords though.

Answer (score 2):

With capo on the 4th fret:

```
Am (C#m) x02210
Dm (F#m) xx0231
F  (A)   x3321x : fingers 3421, T mutes string 6, finger 1 mutes string 1
E  (G#)  022100
```

...this is essentially @JohnBelzaguy's answer except you don't need to play the `F (A)` as a barre chord, not at all! It's not open, but it's also not using a barre. I don't know if you balk at the bass note being the fifth instead of the root, but I often play regular, no capo `F` that way, because a barre on fret 1 is hard for me. I don't mind the fifth in the bass when strumming chords if the chord isn't too low.

Comment: Good solution for banning the barre altogether, +1. Personally I like to avoid the 5th in the bass unless it’s specifically an inversion, how about a compromise, a “baby barre” (just made that up) xx3211, with fingers 3211? It makes the voice leading a little smoother too.

Comment: I like that "baby" barre chord!